# How can I remove Meta Custom Fields buttons from WooCommerce orders list?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to remove the Delete and Update buttons from the custom fields in the WooCommerce order list. I can see a function within `wp-admin/includes/templates.php` is controlling this but I only want it to affect the orders page - I don't want it to affect any other WordPress functionality. Ideally I'd like a PHP solution that physically removes the buttons - not a Javascript solution that hides them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you must pass a var through the order-list.php page template that is the main page that then call some templates.

Answer (score 0):

Due to no answers I have managed to use the following as a workaround. It doesn't physically remove the buttons - but hides them using CSS:

```
function hide_delete_update_buttons($order_id) {

    if(is_admin() && current_user_can('manage_woocommerce')) {

        add_action('admin_head', 'hide_delete_update_buttons_css');

    }

}

function hide_delete_update_buttons_css() {
    echo '<style>.post-type-shop_order #the-list .deletemeta { display: none !important; } .post-type-shop_order #the-list .updatemeta { display: none !important; }</style>';
}

add_action('wp_loaded', 'hide_delete_update_buttons');
```

Not ideal - but will work for now.